# select <option> based on a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html structure

```
<div>
 <select>
   <option value="">select</option>
   <option value="blue">blue</option>
   <option value="red">red</option>
   <option value="orange">orange</option>
   <option value="green">green</option>    
 </select>

 <ul>
  <li>blue</li>
  <li>red</li>
  <li>orange</li>
  <li>green</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I want when user clicks the `<li>`, appropriate `<option>` from `<select>` should get selected automatically,

Comment: are you allowing jQuery or do you want a plain javascript solution?

Comment: Could you post your JS code that you are working with to facilitate the functionality you desire?  We will need that in order to help troubleshoot.

Comment: You don't have control over the HTML code ? I mean: you cannot add links in `<li>` ?

Comment: In other words: _I wanna be spoon fed. Anyone?_

Comment: Where answers are near identical, it is polite SO etiquette to go with the earliest one, unless there is a strong reason not too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach a click event handler to each `li` element that takes the content of the `li` and uses it to set the value of the `select` element:

```js
$('ul > li').on('click', function() {
    $('select').val( $.trim( $(this).text() ) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <select>
   <option value="">select</option>
   <option value="blue">blue</option>
   <option value="red">red</option>
   <option value="orange">orange</option>
   <option value="green">green</option>    
 </select>

 <ul>
  <li>blue</li>
  <li>red</li>
  <li>orange</li>
  <li>green</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: the string `.trim()` method is not available on all browsers.

Comment: Thanks! I have used the standardized jQuery equivalent -- `$.trim()`

Comment: Just as I did... That is the better option for trimming :)

Comment: Actually, [`String.trim()` is available in all modern browsers](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#String.prototype.trim) (IE9+).

Comment: Yes, that's true. This may give another angle to it: [**JavaScript String.trim() Method**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/wg36ehoq/1/

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
    $('select').val($(this).text());
});
```

As whitespace is common in HTML text, you probably want to make it use `$.trim()` too:

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
    $('select').val($.trim($(this).text()));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try this way:

```
$("ul").children().click(function(){

    $("select").find("[value='"+ $(this).text() +"']").prop('selected', true);

})
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/12qn84hb/